# Layering and positioning images in HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css, z-index

I'm creating a simple game using HTML and CSS. I have a background image of an alley way and I'm trying to add images on top of this background as clues in the game. I'm having some difficulty positioning them on the top.

The element I'm dealing with currently is a PNG image of a dagger which I'd like to position on top of the background image of the alley way. Any help would be appreciated. 
The site is [here](http://newmedia.leeds.ac.uk/ug10/cs10mm/scene1.html)

HTML Code -

```
<body>
    <div id="logo">
        <img src="images/key.jpg"  width="3%" height="3%"/>
    </div>    

    <a href="abduction.html" class="back">Back</a>
    <a href="scene2.html" class="next">Next</a>

    <div class="backing">
        <img src="images/scene1.jpg"  width="600" height="600"/>
    </div>

    <img src="images/dagger.png" width="10%" height="10%" id="dagger" />

    </body>
</html>
```

CSS Code -

```
.backing img {
    position:relative;
    z-index:-10;
    float:left;
    margin-left:12%;
    /* box-shadow: inset 0 0 50px 50px  #FFF;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 50px 50px  #FFF;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 50px 50px  #FFF; */
    -moz-border-radius-: 50px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    margin-bottom:5%;
    margin-top:1%;
}

.next {
    position:relative;  
    margin-left:2%;
    z-index:200;
}

.back {
    position:relative;
    margin-left:32%;
    z-index:220;

}

#dagger {
    position:relative;
    z-index:300;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to `position: absolute` the dagger so that it gets on top of the picture

**Update**

You want to `position: relative` the `.backing` and then `position: absolute` both images (dagger and scene) on top of it.

Comment: Is there no way of positioning relatively, as if positioned absolutely, will this not cause issues with screen re-sizing. Eg if this is viewed on a smaller screen? Or do you think it is ok to just do it absolutely?

Comment: screen resizing will be an issue if you use position absolutes everywhere to layout your site. seeing as it is inside a relative container which will hold to the document flow, the two position absolute images won't matter.